# JQuery UI Dialog Box used with MVC

Tags: jquery-ui

I was wondering if anybody has used JQuery UI DialogBox with MVC.
I am using MVC C#. What I like to do is to pass to the DialogBox the controller action
so that from that action, I can return a PartialView() which will populate the DialogBox.

As such, what I like to do is to call the JQuery DialogBox from the view which will call a controller action which will then return a PartialView which will populate the dialogbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried doing something like

```
$.get("YOUR URL HERE", { YOUR DATA HERE }, function(data) {
    $('div').html(data).dialog();
});
```